# Microsoft Graph API UnknownError with 429 code and 'Retry-After' of 86 seconds

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When initially developing an application I came across an `UnknownError` response from all Microsoft Graph API calls when too many requests were made in quick succession. While very aware of the fact this is a throttling message (and rewriting my code to make one third fewer API calls), this response **always** contains a `RetryAfter` value of 86 in the headers.

Is this me misunderstanding what the RetryAfter value is actually saying or a bug on Microsofts end?

**Header:**

```js
{
  "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": {
    "ServerInfo": {
      "DataCenter": "UK South",
      "Slice": "SliceC",
      "Ring": "4",
      "ScaleUnit": "000",
      "Host": "AGSFE_IN_19",
      "ADSiteName": "UKS"
    }
  },
  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
  "request-id": "1194d403-2a35-4bb0-9e06-0473b480cf09",
  "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
  "Retry-After": "86",
  "Date": "Wed, 05 Dec 2018 11:06:18 GMT",
  "client-request-id": "1194d403-2a35-4bb0-9e06-0473b480cf09",
  "Cache-Control": "private",
  "Duration": "57.7795",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

**Content:**

```js
{
  "error": {
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2018-12-05T11:18:14",
      "request-id": "5509a94b-f243-4deb-8b38-631f974181fd"
    },
    "message": "",
    "code": "UnknownError"
  }
}
```

Comment: Each workload (OneNote, Exchange, AAD, etc.) handles throttling a little differently. Which workloads/services are you seeing this from?

Comment: `86` is slang for trash or throw away so I'm guessing from the `unknown error` that you've found some particular edge case that hasn't been fully fleshed out yet.  Just a guess.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur This example is from an Exchange call (reports/getEmailActivityCounts) but I have this issue with SharePoint, Skype for Business and SharePoint too

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify your code to single-thread the requests and have it delay the recommended number of seconds before retrying the current request? That appears to be what their documentation recommends: [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling)

Per their documentation:

> Whenever the throttling threshold is exceeded, Microsoft Graph
> responds with a response similar to this one.
>
> HTTP
>
> Copy HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests Content-Type: application/json
> Retry-After: 2.128
>
> {   "error": {
> "code": "TooManyRequests",
> "innerError": {
> "code": "429",
> "date": "2020-08-18T12:51:51",
> "message": "Please retry after",
> "request-id": "94fb3b52-452a-4535-a601-69e0a90e3aa2",
> "status": "429"
> },
> "message": "Please retry again later."   } } Best practices to handle throttling The following are best practices for handling
> throttling:
>
> Reduce the number of operations per request. Reduce the frequency of
> calls. Avoid immediate retries, because all requests accrue against
> your usage limits. When you implement error handling, use the HTTP
> error code 429 to detect throttling. The failed response includes the
> Retry-After response header. Backing off requests using the
> Retry-After delay is the fastest way to recover from throttling
> because Microsoft Graph continues to log resource usage while a client
> is being throttled.
>
> Wait the number of seconds specified in the Retry-After header. Retry
> the request. If the request fails again with a 429 error code, you are
> still being throttled. Continue to use the recommended Retry-After
> delay and retry the request until it succeeds.

This can most easily be done by single-threading all requests for a given resource type using a work queue. When the retry after error (shown above) occurs, have the queue worker thread pause for the retry-after amount of seconds before sending again.

The resource types supported by the graph API include email, Active Directory queries, etcetera. Throttling is handled on a per resource-type basis so each resource type should have it's own work queue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).